Problem with Django form field styling upon error
I'm building my first website with Django and I have encountered what I think is a really weird problem. I have a form in the page, and I want that, if the user inputs invalid data in one of its fields, that field is marked with a specific CSS style. What I have done is write a validation method (a "clean()" method) that checks the input provided by the user. If it doesn't pass the validation, the class "error" is added to the widget of that input. Then, using CSS, I give that .error class some specific styling.
Here is the problem: the error style is not applied correctly to the fields "name", "last name" and "email" of the form. For instance, when you input an invalid last name, both the field "last name" and "name" get highlighted in red, and when you input an invalid email address, both the "email" and the "name" fields get highlighted.
I have gone over the "forms.py" file a thousand times and I can't figure out what's wrong.
Here is the code of the "forms.py" file:
from django import forms
from .models import Appointment

class AppointmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
        
class Meta:
    model = Appointment
    fields = ['name', 'last_name', 'email', 'date', 'time']
    widgets = {
        "name": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        "last_name": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        "email": forms.EmailInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
    }
            
def clean_name(self):
    name = self.cleaned_data["name"]

    if not name.isalpha():
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['class'] += ' error'
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please, input only letters", code="carac_esp")
        
    
    return name

def clean_last_name(self):
    last_name = self.cleaned_data["last_name"]

    if not last_name.isalpha():
        self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs['class'] += ' error'
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please, input only letters", code="carac_esp")
    
    return last_name

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    allowed_domains = ['gmail.com', 'hotmail.com', 'yahoo.com']

    if not any(email.endswith(domain) for domain in allowed_domains):
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] += ' error'
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please, input a valid email address", code="email_invalid")
    
    return email

The "views.py" file is:
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import TurnoForm

def home(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TurnoForm(request.POST)
        form.is_valid()

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, "home/index2.html", {"form": form})
        
        else:
            
            return render(request, "home/index2.html", {"form": form})
    
    else:

        form = TurnoForm()
        return render(request, "home/index2.html", {"form": form})

Here is a simplified version of the HTML showing only the form that's giving me problems:
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'home/css/style2.css' %}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
     
   
</head>
<body>
    
    

<div id="turnos">
    <fieldset>
        <legend id="legend-turnos">Agende su turno</legend>
        <div id="div_formbox">
            <form method="post" id="form_turnos">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    
                    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                                       
            
                    <div class="input_group">
                        
                        
                        <div class="input_field">
                            {{ form.nombre }}
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="input_field">
                            {{ form.apellido }}
                        </div>
                                                    
                        
                        <div class="input_field">
                            {{ form.email }}
                        </div>
                                                    
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_guardar">Guardar</button>
        
                    </div>
        
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    

And the css error class of the "styles2.css" file used for styling invalid fields:
.error{
    background-color: lightcoral;
}


Please don't delete and repost your question, if you have any clarifications you want to add you can simply edit, which bumps your question up making it more visible to people watching the relevant tags. See: What should I do if no one answers my question?

Please [edit] and add a [mre], given your CSS and the form clean methods I don't see how the one field being invalid will cause some other field to be invalid as well. Share the relevant views and the inputs you are filling up in the form.

I added the "views.py" file and a simplified version of the HTML file "index2.html", including only the form that isn't working. Hope that helps.
If you try to run it and complete the second input field of the form (the one corresponding to the "last_name" field with anything other than letters, you will see that the "name" field also gets marked as invalid.
